# List files in a directory in c

Tags: c, arrays, file-listing

I am using the code below to save file names to an array. I got the code from here [save file names to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291154/save-file-listing-into-array-or-something-else-c). When I run this code it says that there are 5 files in the directory (i.e. `count` is 5), however, there are only 3. Could somebody verify if this is correct or am I making a bad mistake?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <malloc.h>

size_t file_list(const char *path, char ***ls) {
    size_t count = 0;
    size_t length = 0;
    DIR *dp = NULL;
    struct dirent *ep = NULL;

    dp = opendir(path);
    if(NULL == dp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "no such directory: '%s'", path);
        return 0;
    }

    *ls = NULL;
    ep = readdir(dp);
    while(NULL != ep){
        count++;
        ep = readdir(dp);
    }

    rewinddir(dp);
    *ls = calloc(count, sizeof(char *));

    count = 0;
    ep = readdir(dp);
    while(NULL != ep){
        (*ls)[count++] = strdup(ep->d_name);
        ep = readdir(dp);
    }

    closedir(dp);
    return count;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char **files;
    size_t count;
    int i;

    count = file_list("/home/rgerganov", &files);
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", files[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is probably counting the `.` and  `..`.

Comment: Have you tried printing the names of the files you get? Or better yet try to step through your program in a debugger?

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes that is exactly what it is doing! what are `.` and `..`? Thanks

Comment: @articsol `..` is the parent directory, and `.` is the current directory. When doing directory listings, there two special directories should be ignored most of the time.

Comment: Also note that on POSIX systems (like Linux, BSD and macOS) filenames starting with a leading dot are considered *hidden*. So a file named e.g. `.my_secret_file` should not really be counted or displayed unless a flag to count and display hidden flags is passes to your program. That of course goes for the current and parent directories `.` and `..`, they are *also* considered hidden (since they start with a dot).

Answer (score 1):

I asked myself the same question for a school project a few months ago. When you use the dirent structure and you list them accessing the element d_name, it actually counts the directories PLUS the "." and the "..", so it's normal. If you don't want to take them as directories, just create an iterator variable for the loop and add a condition like:

```
int i = 0;
while (condition)
{
    if (ep->d_name[i] == '.' )
    {   
      ++i;
    }
    //do stuff here
}
```

Comment: The AND-ed condition is not required. You want the condition equivalent to true for all names starting with one `.` and all names starting with two `..`. Every name in the latter case will *also* be a name that starts with one `.`. Thus your condition can be simplified to `if (ep->d_name[i] =='.') { }`.

Comment: Yes it's true, didn't know why I put the second one. Thanks i'll edit!

Comment: Thanks folks for your very helpful suggestions!